# Compare columns in CSV and overide newlist

Tags: python-2.7

I'm new to python.  I have two .csv files with identical columns, but my oldlist.csv has been edited for row[9] with employee names, the newlist.csv when generated defaults to certain domains for names.  I want to be able to take the oldlist.csv compare to newlist.csv and override columns in newlist.csv with the data in row[9] from oldlist.csv.  Thanks for your help.

Example: (oldlist) col1, col2    (newlist) col1, col2
                   1234, Bob               1234, Jane

I want to read oldlist, if col1 == col1 in newlist override col2 and I want to contine to write.write(row) for everything matching in col from oldlist

Comment: Unfortunately, csv files are not always delimited with commas.  Can you post a short example?  Do you want every cell in column 9 copied over?

Comment: Example: "oldlist" col1, col2  <br/>